# Get the country code from iPhone device UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, udid

I am trying to get the country code from iPhone device UDID. I found this

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
```

It is working fine in local settings but I want to get the country code from device UDID.  Is it passable?

Thanks...

Comment: UDID contains no dynamic information

Comment: Tell us what are you trying to do. That code can retrieve devices locale and country code, but UDID has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

The UDID contains no information about the country code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];

// Get carrier name
NSString *carrierName = [carrier carrierName];
if (carrierName != nil)
  NSLog(@"Carrier: %@", carrierName);

// Get mobile country code
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
if (mcc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Country Code (MCC): %@", mcc);

// Get mobile network code
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
if (mnc != nil)
  NSLog(@"Mobile Network Code (MNC): %@", mnc);
```

[**For reference check this.**](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/carrier-information-mobile-network-code-mnc-and-mobile-country-code-mcc.html)